# How do I turn a hyperlink in an email to a reply to link?

Tags: marketing-cloud

What is the amscript code to create a hyperlink into a reply to an email. Currently, we are using the following which is a mailto not a replyto.

```
<p class="content-text" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 140%; margin: 0 0 18px 0; color: #23282b; font-weight: normal;">
  <a style="color:#13759b !important;" href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%">Contact your Account Manager</a> to turn on registration and avoid these potential additional fees.
</p>
```

Comment: Hi William. Welcome to SFSE. Your current question is really unclear, and will probably not receive an answer. Please take time to provide a better explanation of your issue, with more context, and a proper example of what you have tried so far to resolve this yourself.

Comment: Please provide more info into what you mean by replyto. Also providing where you define `@link` would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need AMPscript to make a mailto link:

```
<a href="mailto:yourEmailAddress@email.com">Email Me</a>
```

If you are looking for a link that auto populates the randomly generated [Reply Mail Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_reply_mail_management.htm&type=5) email address, i.e., `reply-ff2b34543776c-155_TEXT-7834561-10345387-1@email.yourSAPdomain.com`, I do not believe that is possible. Your end-user would have to hit the reply button in their email client.

> Email Reply Address: The reply address appears in the From name of
>   your subscriber's email client when the subscriber replies to your
>   email. While this information appears in the format of an email
>   message, it is not a valid email address on its own. The address
>   directs the reply to RMM for processing. Define this address in the
>   Reply Mail Management feature or via a sender profile. If you use a
>   sender profile to define the email reply address, you can enable the
>   email message to use a multitude of email reply addresses.

Comment: I believe these two strings give you the reply name/email

%%replyname%% Your reply name, as defined in your account settings
%%replyemailaddress%% Your reply email address

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5